# GWT - formatting numbers in default locale regardless of selected locale

Tags: java, gwt, internationalization

I'm trying to format and parse numbers using GWT's NumberFormat but I would like to use the default format (for ex. that of EN locale) regardless of user selected locale, so users can select any language, but I want the numbers to be displayed and parsed using the default format (for ex. 1,234.89).

Is there a way to do this?

EDIT:

For ex. this code only works in EN locale, in RU I get NumberFormatException

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getFormat("#,##0.00");
String n = "1,234.89"; 
double value = format.parse(n);
//do something with value...
```

I would need to get a NumberFormat instance for locale EN, but I can't find any method/constructor in the javadocs that can do this.

Comment: Please show how you do the formatting now and what you have tried already.

Answer (score 0):

I you have the number you should use `NumberFormat.format`, not `NumberFormat.parse`:

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getFormat("#,##0.00");
Double n = 1234.89;
RootPanel.get().add(new HTML("Number: " + format.format(n)));
```

I you already have a  formated String representation of the number, you don't need `NumberFormat`:

```
String n = "1,234.89"; 
RootPanel.get().add(new HTML("Number: " + n));
```

Comment: That was just an example, I would need the double value of the number to manipulate it.  I've edited my post.

Comment: Ok. I just dug into `NumberFormat` code and it seams that you could achieve what you want by setting the `NumberConstants` at the `NumberFormat` construction. Except that is not possible. `NumberFormat` constructor is protected and there is no way to specify a fixed `NumberConstants` after creation (except `setForcedLatinDigits` which is not useful for you). So unless you want to do an hugly hack, I would say that it's not possible to use `NumberFormat` to do what you want. Maybe I'm wrong, maybe someone else see a way...

Answer (score 0):

`NumberFormat` always parses a localized text. It uses `NumberConstants` witch are instantiated via deferred binding according to current locale. Unfortunately you can not force using other `NumberConstants`.

But you know the default grouping separator (`,`) and decimal separator (`.`). You can also get the grouping and decimal separator for current locale. So you just need to replace them before parsing.

```
String n = "1,234.89";
n = n.replace(",", LocaleInfo.getCurrentLocale().getNumberConstants().groupingSeparator());
n = n.replace(".", LocaleInfo.getCurrentLocale().getNumberConstants().decimalSeparator());
double value = format.parse(n);
```

This should work for any locale.

To format a number with default locale just do the opposite replacements after formatting in current locale.